# Trying to copy a .txt file into a private class variable using a buffered reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am creating a method which copies a .txt file into a private class variable however I am getting a runtime error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I cannot seem to find any problems with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class WordList
{
  private ArrayList<String> words;
  public void main(String[] args)
  {
  }
  public void arrayListConstructor(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    this.words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cities.txt"));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
      this.words.add(line);
      line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: which line causes the NPE?

Comment: @peeskillet What good will that do? It's the effectively the same code, just bad style (side effects in a branch test).

Comment: Is there any code the `main` you're leaving out?

Comment: The `NullPointerException` itself is a bug in DrJava, not your code. But it might occur because your code doesn't provide a valid entry point: `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 2):

Fix you class' main signature

```
public static void main (String [] args)
```

Comment: @JustDanyul funny thing, I was just trying to get 200 daily for a badge run, however I was slow and got stuck at 185. So in fact I wasn't fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to execute that main method, then it should be static. And so should your arrayListConstructor method